# traceroute shows stars but netcat reaches the port

Tags: linux, udp, netcat, traceroute

I have several (virtual) machines with `Centos 7` in the same subnet with several instances of my app running on each of them. I need to test how the apps can reach each other by UDP.

I'm trying to access one machine from another one by `tracerote`. So I check on host1:

```
# traceroute host2 -U -p 3001

traceroute to host2 (<ip>), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

It looks like UDP packets are filtered. But then I try `netcat` (on host 1 again):

```
# nc -u host2 3001
qwerty1
qwerty2
qwerty3
```

And it works somehow! **How can it be?**

By the way, traceroute by TCP reaches the destination in one hop as it should be in one subnet:

```
# traceroute host2 -T -p 3001
traceroute to host2 (<ip>), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  host2 (<ip>)  0.663 ms  0.707 ms *
```

The question is does UDP work or not after all? Or is there a reliable way to test it? The app doesn't work correctly unfortunately and I want be sure it is or it's not the fault of the underlying infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

The output from netcat just shows that the packets can be send to this target and that no error comes back. This will also happen if there is a firewall in between which simply discards all UDP packets. And this kind of firewall would also produces the output you see with traceroute: if packets get discarded then they cannot fail later with ICMP TTL exceeded.

Comment: But it returns at once if I try a closed port:

```
# nc -u host2 4001
qwerty1
Ncat: Connection refused.
```

Comment: @MikeSiomkin: The firewall can be configured to let some ports through and not others. Try using port 4001 with traceroute.